# testing to check if a function calls another function if requirements are met

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I am new to unit testing and was working on an example problem where I am getting very confused.

In the example below, I need to test if function onPost is called, after onSubmitHandler is called, given that the boolean value of employee is true.

```
class Employee extends React.Component{

    function onSubmitHandler(){
        if(employee){
            this.onPost()
        }
        else {
            this.onFailure()
        }

    }

    function onPost(){
        return something
    }

    function onFailure(){
        return something
    }

    render(){
        return(<EmployeeForm onAdd = {onSubmitHandler} />
        )
    }
}
```

Below is the test I created.

```
   test('onPost is called',()=>{
        const wrapper  = shallow (<Employee/>)
        wrapper.instance().onSubmitHandler()
        Employee.onPost= jest.fn()
        expect(Employee.onPost).toBeCalled()


    })
```

This test is failing and I was wondering if I could get some clarification on how to go about testing the function. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, give more details about Employee component, who is the employee variable in onSubmitHandler function ? How do you set it ?
About your test, first you need to use shallow to get a wrapper of your rendered component, after that, get the instance of your component, so you can test everything you need:

```
test("onPost is called", () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<Employee />)
  const instance = wrapper.instance()
  instance.onPost = jest.fn()

  instance.onSubmitHandler()
  expect(instance.onPost).toBeCalled()
});
```

As your component is too simple I could understand what you need and I'm providing a complete example test of your Employee component with type script and a better approach to test if a method is called using *jest.spyOn*.

**1 - Employee component**

```
import * as React from "react";

export interface Employee {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

interface Props {
  employee: Employee;
}

export default class EmployeeComp extends React.Component<Props> {
  constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);
  }

  onSubmitHandler = () => {
    if (this.props.employee) {
      this.onPost();
    } else {
      this.onFailure();
    }
  };

  onPost = () => {
    return true;
  };

  onFailure = () => {
    return false;
  };

  render() {
    return <div>Some content</div>;
  }
}
```

**2 - Complete test**

```
import * as React from "react";
import { shallow } from "enzyme";
import EmployeeComp, { Employee } from "src/some";

const employee: Employee = {
  id: 10,
  name: "Mario 64"
};

describe("Employee component", () => {
  it("should render", () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<EmployeeComp employee={employee} />);
    expect(wrapper).toBeDefined();
    expect(wrapper.find("div").length).toBe(1);
  });

  it("should call onPost method when has employee", () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<EmployeeComp employee={employee} />);
    const instance: EmployeeComp = wrapper.instance() as EmployeeComp;
    const spy = jest.spyOn(instance, "onPost");

    instance.onSubmitHandler();
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });

  it("should call onFailure method when has NO employee", () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<EmployeeComp employee={null} />);
    const instance: EmployeeComp = wrapper.instance() as EmployeeComp;
    const spy = jest.spyOn(instance, "onFailure");

    instance.onSubmitHandler();
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

Comment: This is very helpful ,especially for a beginner like me. Thank you.